# Minimum number of students, where 100 students from the same state go to the same university

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I was given the following question:

[image]

I thought of the problem like this. Each of the $50$ states represents a box, and I want $100$ people in the same box. By the pigeon-hole principle, we are trying to find $N/50 \geq 100 \Longrightarrow N = 50*100 = 5000$. It turns out I was close, my textbook gave the answer $4,951$ and I'm wondering why I was wrong?

Comment: You're on the right track, but you've over shot the mark a bit. Think of it this way. The "worst case scenario" is if each state contributes $99$ people. In this case, $99*50 = 4950$ is insufficient to guarantee at least 100 students come from the same state. If we include $1$ more person, then we see that at least $100$ students must come from the same state. Can you make this thinking rigorous using the pigeonhole principle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of the pigeonhole principle are you using?  There are various ways of doing it with floor and/or ceiling functions, but IMHO the simplest version is the one involving *strict* inequalities.

> If more than $nk$ objects are placed into $n$ boxes, there must be a box containing more than $k$ objects.

In your problem you want to end up with at least $100$ objects in the same box, that is, more than $99$, so $k=99$.  Clearly you have $n=50$ boxes.  To guarantee what you want, you need more than $50\times99$ objects altogether, so the smallest possibility is $50\times99+1$.

Comment: The version I am using is: "If $N$ objects are placed into $k$
boxes, then there is at least one box containing at least $N/k$ objects." I see how your version says the same thing. So because we have $n = 50$ (the states) and $k = 99$ (we want 100 students) and the smallest possible quantity that is more than $nk$ is 50*99 + 1.

Comment: IMHO my version is easier to use, but of course it's up to you.

Comment: Your version was better in this case, thanks for the great answer. Are there any other versions I should be aware of?

Comment: I don't know any versions which are significantly different from those you have seen already.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $4951 = 99\times 50 + 1$.

---

If you have 4950 students, it may be the case that there are 99 per state. If you have one more, there must be at least one state with 100 students (the "worst" that can happen is that all but one state have 99 students, and the last one has 100).